# Why boost python built library without any export function?

Tags: python, c++, boost, compilation, dllexport

I built boost python (1.55) without any errors or warnings. 
Here is list:

```
C:\Programming\boost>b2 toolset=msvc-11.0 link=static variant=release threading=multi runtime-link=static --with-python
link.jam: No such file or directory
Building the Boost C++ Libraries.

Component configuration:
    - atomic                   : not building
    - chrono                   : not building
    - context                  : not building
    - coroutine                : not building
    - date_time                : not building
    - exception                : not building
    - filesystem               : not building
    - graph                    : not building
    - graph_parallel           : not building
    - iostreams                : not building
    - locale                   : not building
    - log                      : not building
    - math                     : not building
    - mpi                      : not building
    - program_options          : not building
    - python                   : building
    - random                   : not building
    - regex                    : not building
    - serialization            : not building
    - signals                  : not building
    - system                   : not building
    - test                     : not building
    - thread                   : not building
    - timer                    : not building
    - wave                     : not building

...patience...
...patience...
...found 1654 targets...
...updating 30 targets...
compile-c-c++ bin.v2\libs\python\build\msvc-11.0\release\link-static\runtime-link-static\threading-multi\numeric.obj
numeric.cpp
..........................
compile-c-c++ bin.v2\libs\python\build\msvc-11.0\release\link-static\runtime-link-static\threading-multi\object\function_doc_signature.obj
function_doc_signature.cpp
msvc.archive bin.v2\libs\python\build\msvc-11.0\release\link-static\runtime-link-static\threading-multi\libboost_python-vc110-mt-s-1_55.lib
common.copy stage\lib\libboost_python-vc110-mt-s-1_55.lib
bin.v2\libs\python\build\msvc-11.0\release\link-static\runtime-link-static\threading-multi\libboost_python-vc110-mt-s-1_55.lib
Скопировано файлов:         1.
...updated 30 targets...

The Boost C++ Libraries were successfully built!
The following directory should be added to compiler include paths:
    C:/Programming/boost
The following directory should be added to linker library paths:
    C:\Programming\boost\stage\lib
C:\Programming\boost>
```

**EDITED:**

But if I add it to my project (References -> Linker -> Input -> Additional dependencies), I get linker errors, such as:

```
PyRunnable.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) class boost::python::api::object __cdecl boost::python::api::getitem(class boost::python::api::object const &,class boost::python::api::object const &)" (__imp_?getitem@api@python@boost@@YA?AVobject@123@ABV4123@0@Z)
PyRunnable.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) class boost::python::api::object __cdecl boost::python::api::getattr(class boost::python::api::object const &,char const *)" (__imp_?getattr@api@python@boost@@YA?AVobject@123@ABV4123@PBD@Z)
PyRunnable.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) protected: __thiscall boost::python::detail::str_base::str_base(void)" (__imp_??0str_base@detail@python@boost@@IAE@XZ)
```

If I use dumpbin /symbols , I even can find methods that are unresolved. So, they are inside, but VS2012 ignores them somehow.
Why?

In Additional dependencies field there is:

```
libboost_system-vc110-mt-1_55.lib
libboost_program_options-vc110-mt-1_55.lib
libboost_filesystem-vc110-mt-1_55.lib
```

And no problems with them. But if I add there libboost_python-vc120-mt-1_55.lib or not, I still get 15 linker errors.
What do I do wrong way?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

That's normal. The `dumpbin` `/exports` option is for showing functions exported from a PE file (e.g. a DLL), not for listing the functions in a COFF library.

To list the functions in a COFF library, use the `/symbols` option:

```
dumpbin /symbols libboost_python-vc110-mt-s-1_55.lib
```

Comment: but if I add this lib to project (References - Linker - Input - Additional Dependencies), I get 15 linker errors, such as:
1>PyRunnable.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: class boost::python::str __thiscall boost::python::detail::str_base::join(class boost::python::api::object const &)const " (__imp_?join@str_base@detail@python@boost@@QBE?AVstr@34@ABVobject@api@34@@Z)

Comment: I search for /symbols output and found there this method. Now I don't understand why it don't work at all...

BD7 00000000 UNDEF  notype ()    External     | ?join@str_base@detail@python@boost@@QBE?AVstr@34@ABVobject@api@34@@Z (public: class boost::python::str __thiscall boost::python::detail::str_base::join(class boost::python::api::object const &)const )

Comment: From the `__imp` in the symbol name in the linker error, it looks like you're trying to dynamically link Boost Python into your application (needing a DLL import .lib file) but have built Boost Python as a static library. You could either switch to linking it statically, or build it as a dynamic library.

Comment: Thank you very much. It looks like I VS adds static and dynamic libraries _different_ways_.
Then I don't understand, how to link library statically using VS2012.
And why boost::system, built statically, is perfectly added throw Additinal Dependencies, but boost::python needs some more things to do?

Comment: I edited post to make it more correct. Thank you very much for your help.